# VPS para Magento O que preciso de saber?

Tags: php, linux, magento

Eu à anos que só uso servidores partilhados com a plataforma Opencart, no entanto dava-me imenso jeito agora criar uma loja em Magento, mas li que pode ser lento e nao resultar bem em alojamentos partilhados pelo que teria de ir para um VPS. Gostava de saber se será mesmo necessário ter um VPS e se sim, o que devo aprender e onde?

Eu estive a pesquisar e desde já peço desculpa pela minha ignorância mas eu estive a ver o vps do digitalocean e tem esta funcionalidade https://www.digitalocean.com/features/one-click-apps/ seria mais fácil para um utilizador iniciante como eu instalar o Ubuntu ou CentOS, o LAMP e o Magento no VPS, é o suficiente? Que mais poderei precisar? Vi também o painel serverpilot.io que penso que iria facilitar um pouco as coisas e pelo que dizem instala uma firewall, será suficientemente segura?

Não tenho experiencia em VPS é certo mas estou disposto a aprender o que for necessário. Espero ter sido claro nas minhas perguntas.

Obrigado desde já pela vossa ajuda!

Comment: inicialmente, se voce  nao conhece te indico utilizar uma empresa que tenha esse conhecimento para nao gerar problemas principalmente com a plataforma magento

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: `li que pode ser lento` -> leitura por leitura, eu também já li que a Terra é plana e que água potável dá câncer. Não fique apenas pela leitura, ponha a mão na massa e descubra a verdade.

Answer (score 1):

O VPS ou Cloud Server são as melhores soluções para utilizar o Magento em seus projetos. O tamanho da memória e do processador depende muito de quantas lojas e quantos acessos diários terá o servidor. Você pode ter várias lojas e milhares de acessos, porém irá precisar de mais processador, memória Ram, espaço em disco e banda de internet. Se for apenas uma loja, um cloud de 512Mb da digital ocean pode ser o suficiente.

Em relação ao sistema operacional, recomendo o Ubuntu que é melhor para iniciantes do que o CentOs. Será necessário conhecer sobre os comandos do linux, e como instalar o LAMP. E, não é só isso, você provavelmente irá precisar instalar módulos do PHP, o que no Ubuntu é extremamente fácil.

O ServerPilot pode ser sim uma solução viável e segura para o seu ambiente. Lembrando que o problema de segurança principal desses portais e lojas online atualmente, é a utilização de servidor (alojamento) compartilhado, pois abre vulnerabilidades para as suas aplicações, portanto um servidor VPS ou Cloud são soluções mais seguras. Se você se preocupa com segurança, lembre-se de utilizar sempre as versões mais recentes dos softwares (Magento, Lamp, PHP, etc).

Para instalar, considerando que você utilizará a ultima versão, segue a documentação de instalação:

[Instalação Magento 2.0](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

Qualquer dúvida, estamos ai! Abraço!